# Git alias to cd into newly cloned repo

Tags: git, regex

I have some useful git aliases that I use, mostly from here:

https://haacked.com/archive/2014/07/28/github-flow-aliases/#the-list

One thing I am missing though, is whenever I clone a repository I will 100% of the time want to cd into that folder right after.

Is there a way to make this alias?

I'm assumning it would involve taking the first row returned in STDOUT and parse it with regex `Cloning into '(.+?)'...`, then cd into that folder.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97920/how-to-cd-automatically-after-git-clone, although that doesn't cover aliases specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shell `function` would likely be more suitable than an `alias` in  a modern shell (unless you are using `tcsh`). For ZSH this might look something like:

```
function clonecd {
  local dir
  if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
    git clone -- $1 $2 || return
    dir=$2
  else
    git clone -- $1 || return
    dir=${1:t}
  fi
  builtin cd $dir
}
```

which allows for both the `clonecd git://.../somerepo` and `clonecd git://.../somerepo someotherdir` forms, plus some assorted error checking.

A POSIX shell such as `bash` will instead need quoting of variables (`git clone -- "$1"` and so forth [to avoid stupidity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)), and probably some other means than `${1:t}` to extract the tail of the repository path.

Comment: `clonecd:cd:9: no such file or directory: project.git`